# ionic 3 slide has an issue with autoplay

Tags: ionic3, slide, autoplay

I am using ionic 3.

Here is my template

```
  <ion-slides autoplay="2000" loop="true" speed="500" pager="true" class="sliderNews">
<ion-slide *ngFor="let slides of items | async">
  <img class="card-img" [src]="slides.slideImg"/>
  <div class="card-title"><span class="card-title-cat"  [innerHTML]="slides.title"></span></div>
</ion-slide>
```

Here is my ts file
[slider.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJ4M0.png)

But I am getting this error

```
Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasAttribute' of undefined
```

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your .ts file please?

Comment: I put a picture of my ts file.

Comment: You have type error. If you want help share full code as from what you shared its unclear where are you expecting “hasAttribute” property

Comment: Thanks @SergeyRudenko, I shared the full code in slider.ts picture inside the question. Can you find it?

Comment: Did you read this one: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/10940

Comment: Yeah and it doesn't work.